# Why does referencing a concatenated pandas dataframe return multiple entries?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

When I create a dataframe using concat like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3],'b':[4]})
dfc = pd.concat([dfa,dfb])
```

And I try to reference like I would for any other DataFrame I get the following result:

```
>>> dfc['a'][0]
0    1
0    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

I would expect my concatenated DataFrame to behave like a normal DataFrame and return the integer that I want like this simple DataFrame does:

```
>>> dfa['a'][0]
1
```

I am just a beginner, is there a simple explanation for why the same call is returning an entire DataFrame and not the single entry that I want? Or, even better, an easy way to get my concatenated DataFrame to respond like a normal DataFrame when I try to reference it? Or should I be using something other than concat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mistaken what normal behavior is.  `dfc['a'][0]` is a label lookup and matches anything with an index value of `0` in which there are two because you concatenated two dataframes with index values including `0`.

in order to specify position of `0`

```
dfc['a'].iloc[0]
```

or you could have constructed `dfc` like

```
dfc = pd.concat([dfa,dfb], ignore_index=True)
dfc['a'][0]
```

Both returning

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED** (thx [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared)'s comment)

Use `append()` instead `pd.concat()`:

```
dfc = dfa.append(dfb, ignore_index=True)
dfc['a'][0]
1
```

Comment: Yes. You got other results?